# How to import spring source code into eclipse to be able to read it?

Tags: spring, gradle

How can I import spring source into Eclipse using gradle?
I would like to have CTRL+SHIFT+G capabilities.
Any kind of help is very much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advices, but this worked for me (using gradle):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE'
}
```

Best regards,
mismas

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Eclipse Class Decompiler Plugin**.you can find this on eclipse market place using this you can view source code of compiler jars/class files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Gradle project depending on Spring libraries then import it into Eclipse the sources should be available. At least that's the default behavior that can be customized as shown in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html (this page is linked from Gradle user guide - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html)